# How to send complex array to asp.net mvc controller with JSONP

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jsonp, getjson

How can i **SEND** complex type object with array inside it using JSONP

```
 var product= {categories:[ {id:1,text:"cat 1"},{id:2,text:"cat 2"}],id:43,price:3535};
 $.getJSON(url ,product, function (data) {

 //i can get the data from the server but i cant pass the complex array to the server
 });
```

and on asp.net mvc server:

```
    public JsonpResult Create(Product product)
    {
        string thisisok = product.id;
        string needthis = product.categories[0].text;           
        return new JsonpResult { Data = true };
    }
```

how should i pass the complex json using the "getjson" method,
i cant use ajax request because its need to be cross domain

Comment: The best way to do cross-domain AJAX calls, is with a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Well I had a similar issue; I wanted to pass an array of objects to the controller using jsonp and always I received it as null! (I mean, by GET method and with a callback feature to cross the domain)

Lets suppose I have a complex class: SearchCriteria

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
    public string destination {get; set;}
    public string destinationTitle { get; set; }        
    public string departure { get; set; }
    public string month { get; set; }
    public string nights { get; set; }
    public string cruiseline { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to pass an array of SearchCriteria to my Controller.

I found the solution creating an attribute:

```
public class JsonpFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Param { get; set; }
    public Type JsonDataType { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            string inputContent = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params[Param];                
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = serializer.Deserialize(inputContent, JsonDataType);
            filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
 [JsonpFilter(Param = "criterias", JsonDataType = typeof(SearchCriteria[]))]
 public JsonpResult getResultSet(SearchCriteria[] criterias)
 {            
     foreach (SearchCriteria sc in criterias)
     {
         // TODO (normalize criteria, etc..)
     }
     return Jsonp(new { content = RenderPartialViewToString("getResults", criterias)});
 }
```

In the client script when I call the method:

```
// Populate the Array of objects

var criteria = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    criteria.push({ "destination": $("#DestinationValue" + i).val(),
                    "departure": $("#PortValue" + i).val(),
                    "month": $("#Month" + i).val(),
                    "nights": $("#Nights" + i).val(),
                    "cruiseline": $("#CruiselineValue" + i).val()});                
}

// Call the controller; note i do not specify POST method and I specify "callback" in order to enable jsonp that cross the domain.

$.ajax({ 
  url: "getResultSet?callback=?", 
  dataType: 'json', 
  data: {"criterias" : JSON.stringify(criteria)}, 
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success: function (data) {
              // call return from the controller
           }
});
```

I hope this could help someone.

Comment: Thanks for this - nearly sorted me out except that `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType` is always `""` - any ideas? Using exactly the same ajax call as you (except for different data)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return JSONP from your server, why are you returning JSON from your controller action? This being said the JSONP implementation of jQuery relies on adding `<script>` tags to the DOM and as you know a `<script>` tag sends a GET request to fetch the resource. That's a limitation of jQuery's JSONP implementation.

But firstyou need to have your server return JSONP. You could write a custom ActionResult that will return JSONP:

```
public class JsonpResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly object _obj;

    public JsonpResult(object obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var callbackname = context.HttpContext.Request["callback"];
        var jsonp = string.Format("{0}({1})", callbackname, serializer.Serialize(_obj));
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Write(jsonp);
    }
}
```

and then in your controller action return this result:

```
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    ...
    return new JsonpResult(new { success = true });
}
```

and then a client could consume this action but using a GET request (and all the limitations this has such as sending complex objects as the one you have shown):

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/products/create', product, function(result) {
    alert(result.success);
});
```

If you need to send complex objects I think that the best would be to setup a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain and then send a `$.ajax` request to your script.

Comment: the problem is not to get the jsonp from the server

Comment: Well, it's definitely a problem with the code you have shown us. If you are saying that it is not a problem then why is your controller action returning Json? JSON is not the same thing as JSONP. But as I said the jQuery implementation of JSONP works with GET requests only so even if you manage to return a proper JSONP from your controller action (as shown in my answer) you might hit a stone with this limitation. You might go with a server side proxy.