# Posting JSON data to cross domain using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am working on webform based web application form which I want to send JSON data to one MVC application. Both are on different domain.

Here is my ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://localhost:52099/Controller/Index',   
    data: JSON.stringify(response.d),
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (response) {
        alert("done");
    },
    error: function(e){
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

Here is my action method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(ClientInformation model)
    {
        return(View);
    }
```

Index method is getting invoked but I am not getting parameter values. What should I need to do? Is there anything incorrect here?

Here is my data as response.d:

```
[{"Id":50345520,"FirstName":"Matthew","LastName":"McCauley","MiddleName":"","Suffix":null,"NPI":"1083043491","Address":"614 Esplanade St.","City":"Piscataway","State":"NJ","ZIP":"08854","Country":"United States","SubscriberFirstName":null,"SubscriberLastName":null,"SubscriberMiddleName":null,"SubscriberSSN":null,"SubscriberDOB":null,"SubscriberGender":null,"SubscriberSuffix":null,"SubscriberAddress":null,"SubscriberCity":null,"SubscriberState":null,"SubscriberZIP":null,"SubscriberCountry":null,"VisitDate":"\/Date(1483295400000)\/"}]"
```

And

```
public class ClientInformation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string NPI { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZIP { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberFirstName { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberLastName { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberMiddleName { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberSSN { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubscriberDOB { get; set; }
    public int SubscriberGender { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberSuffix { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberAddress { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberCity { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberState { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberZIP { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberCountry { get; set; }
    public DateTime? VisitDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is `response.d`?

Comment: actually this ajax is under the success of another ajax call. in response.d I am getting json data.

Comment: For starters you need to implement CORS server side for requests that are cross origin. Not hard to research how to implement it

Comment: What I need to do for that?

Comment: does `response.d` have data in it? Are you sure, try doing an alert. If you are sure, then please show the response.d json and the code for `ClientInformation`

Comment: please have a look at question

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Any luck?

Comment: @Div: I tried that already.

Comment: @Ankita, Then, you should mention to the question, what you've already tried.

Comment: @Ankita: Just noticed, on ajax call `type: 'POST'` and method type is `[HttpGet]`

Comment: @Ankita use List<ClientInformation> model insead of ClientInformation model in your action method parameter because your response.d is an array which you are posting. Also please change this action method to HttpPost instead of HttpGet as you are sending post request from ajax method. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your response.d is an array so to receive this data on your controller action method you need to use a list:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<ClientInformation> model)
{
    return(View);
}
```

One more thing i noticed is that your are sending a post request form ajax and on your action method you are using HttpGet please change that to HttpPost as well.

Now after changing ClientInformation model to List model you will get complete data of array response.d in the model object.

I tried it in my application by sending following ajax request to above action method and i am able to receive all the data properly:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var r = [{ "Id": 50345520, "FirstName": "Matthew", "LastName": "McCauley", "MiddleName": "", "Suffix": null, "NPI": "1083043491", "Address": "614 Esplanade St.", "City": "Piscataway", "State": "NJ", "ZIP": "08854", "Country": "United States", "SubscriberFirstName": null, "SubscriberLastName": null, "SubscriberMiddleName": null, "SubscriberSSN": null, "SubscriberDOB": null, "SubscriberGender": null, "SubscriberSuffix": null, "SubscriberAddress": null, "SubscriberCity": null, "SubscriberState": null, "SubscriberZIP": null, "SubscriberCountry": null, "VisitDate": "\/Date(1483295400000)\/" }];
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '/Employee/Test',
            data: JSON.stringify(r),
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (response) {
                alert("done");
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But ajax call does not invoke my post method. Any idea why?

Comment: Then that may be any other issue.. Are you getting this data with HttpGet request after changing to List<>? As in your post you mentioned that action method is invoking but data is null? @Ankita

Comment: No, I did not get it in GET method.

Comment: When you are changing your action method to HttpPost, in that case your action method is invoking or not? @Ankita

Comment: For me everything is working fine and i am able to recieve the data properly in my List<>. You can see my $.ajax code and action method code in my post. @Ankita

Comment: The only difference I can find is, you have place ajax call in document.ready and I have my ajax function within success of another ajax call

Comment: That is okay because i am invoking my function on page load and you are invoking it from some other function.

Comment: One more thing I have mentioned that ajax function is within Webform project. I am trying to invoke action method of different MVC application.

Comment: @Ankita You are right, with JSONP request we can't post data so you are using right verb HTTPGET on your action method. If we use POST with jsonp it automatically converts it to GET. Now you are getting null values on your action  method because we are sending array to it which is a complex type. So to receive it on your action method you need to create an action filter as described in below link. Same problem discussed in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462328/how-to-send-complex-array-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-with-jsonp    Hope this helps you.